# find index of first element in array that matches some condition

Tags: python, numpy

I want a pretty way to find the index of the first element of an np.array, that matches some condition.
The condition is:

```
array>constant
```

This is my solution:

```
first_index = ((array<constant)*np.arange(len(array))).argmax()+1
```

Is there a prettier one-line way to do this in numpy or python?

Comment: Well that solution is one-line. Why the +1? Perhaps [argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)?

Comment: But it's not pretty, and I was wondering it there is a prettier way

Comment: np.argwhere(array>constant)[0] works great, thanks!

Comment: Does your solution in the code actually works, it appears it returns the last index.

Comment: It returns the last index of the opposite condition(+1), I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 2):

Argmax goes sequentially if you look at the document: so it will find the first true value

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

So you could use

```
np.argmax(array<val)
```

Comment: Thanks, for my purposes I need np.argmin(), but the principle works. (I am looking for the opposite condition than the one in the expression).

Comment: @ShayLempert `argmax` simply finds the first element that has met the condition and is `True`. If you want it the other way around, switch the direction of inequality instead of using `argmin`.